# Fancy Box and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, fancybox-2

I'm trying to use fancyBox2 to display Google Maps. When I copy and paste the appropriate link that exists on the demo page (http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancybox-download/google-maps-fancybox/fancybox-google-maps.html) into my web page the map works just fine. Here's a copy of that link.

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" title="Yankees Suck!" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=fenway+park&amp;sll=42.291762,-71.425894&amp;sspn=0.20368,0.315514&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Fenway+Park&amp;hnear=Fenway+Park,+4+Yawkey+Way,+Boston,+Massachusetts+02215-3409&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=10154405128186028253&amp;ll=42.346751,-71.096946&amp;output=embed"><img src="demo/img1s.jpg"></a>
```

But when I try to replace the above map with a different one, I can't get the map to appear, though the modal window functions as it should. I'm not sure where the error is. Here's the map location I would like to use.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Parque+Nacional+Manuel+Antonio,+Cant%C3%B3n+de+Aguirre,+Puntarenas/@9.392308,-84.1369879,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8fa1719c9ba9f54b:0x95e66139ce5c4a86

Could somebody kindly illustrate what the proper link should look like? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Kind regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I use jquery 1.7.1 and use the provided "embed" URL (instructions below).

I replaced the URL in the example with one from [your linked map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Parque+Nacional+Manuel+Antonio,+Cant%C3%B3n+de+Aguirre,+Puntarenas/@9.392308,-84.1369879,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8fa1719c9ba9f54b:0x95e66139ce5c4a86) (I clicked on the "hamburger menu" to the left of "Parque Nacional Manuel Antonio, Cantón de Aguirre, Puntarenas", then "share or embed", then on the "Embed Map" tab. The URL inside the iframe: `<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d7872.6622650279005!2d-84.1369879!3d9.392308!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1451580267451" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`)

[Live example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FancyBox_Example.html)

The URL is:

```
href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d7872.6622650279005!2d-84.1369879!3d9.392308!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8fa1719c9ba9f54b%3A0x95e66139ce5c4a86!2sParque+Nacional+Manuel+Antonio!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1451580042799"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response. I am using query 1.7.1, and the program is working just fine. The problem is with the map.

Comment: What is the problem with the map?  Does it work in the link in my answer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Your link/example works just fine, and as I mentioned above I can get the Fancybox to work properly. What I'm trying to do is use a text link to trigger Fancybox, which would then display the map. I don't want to embed the map on the web page using the iframe tag, as your example does. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Embedded Google Maps need to be in iframe's as far as I know.  If you don't want that, you probably need to use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 to make your map (or a static map).

Comment: OK, thanks. Ideally I'd prefer to have the maps embedded in a pop-up window of some kind, and not on the web page itself.

Comment: I don't understand how that rules out the fancybox example provided.  Perhaps you can update your question to clarify what you are trying to do.  As I read the question currently, the issue was "I can't get the map to appear, what would the proper link should look like? ".

Comment: Hi, I apologize for the confusion. If you remove the following code on your example page, and replace it with text, say Costa Rica Map, you'll see that if you click on the link Fancybox will open and the map will be displayed. This is what I want, as you don't have to display the map on the webpage, there will only be a text link. 

<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Fenway+Park,+4+Yawkey+Way,+Boston,+Massachusetts+02215&zoom=14&size=260x150">

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the static map as the anchor to open the fancy box?  Then don't use it, I based my example on the one you provided, it isn't really relevant to the answer (or the question you asked).

Comment: Hi. First the good news, everything is working the way I want and I'll be purchasing a copy of FancyBox. Thanks so much for your help. Now, regarding my initial post. The problem was that I was substituting the URL in the Demo map with an incorrect URL. Remember, I didn't want to embed the maps on my web page, only place a link that would open the maps in Fancybox. So, rather than use to the code in the "Embed Map" tab, I used the code in the "Share" tag, or just copied the URL from the browser. In both cases the maps failed, and that's why/when I posted my message. Thanks again.